# Playing multiple video simultaneously in HTML video tag in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I created a simple HTML page with multiple video tag & trying to play all video simultaneously on native `WebView` of Android 4.2.2. However it is working on Chrome browser of Android 4.2.2. also  tried to `chrome-webview` bundle from GitHub in my application to use android-chrome `WebView` class object instead of native `webkit-engine/webview`. It display player on HTML page but any of video doesn't get played.

I do not understand why this is happen because i have even tried `chrome-webview` code and get same result, please suggest me some solution or alternative for same.

I can share my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function init() {
      enableVideoClicks();
    }

    function enableVideoClicks() {
      var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video') || [];
      for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        // TODO: use attachEvent in IE
        videos[i].addEventListener('click', function(videoNode) {
          return function() {
            videoNode.play();
          };
        }(videos[i]));
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">


  <video src="movie1.mp4" poster = "l.jpg" width="400" height="300" autoplay controls loop></video>
  <video src="movie2.mp4" poster = "l.jpg" width="400" height="300" autoplay controls loop></video>
  <video src="movie3.mp4" poster = "l.jpg" width="400" height="300" autoplay controls loop></video>



  ...

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perhaps this can help you: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging
are you sure it finds video1-4

Comment: I faced this issue and could not solve it. After some time, the requirements changed and I never came back on it. Here is a link to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031908/unable-to-play-video-using-webview

Comment: @ligi Yes, its find all video,  i also  have been tried on android 4.4.2 and its works fine but at  in android 4.2.2 it can play on one video at a time

Answer (score -1):

Yes it possible. See the following answers for more information:

[Enabling HTML5 video playback in android WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259636/enabling-html5-video-playback-in-android-webview)

[Playing HTML5 video on fullscreen in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768837/playing-html5-video-on-fullscreen-in-android-webview)

[WebView and HTML5 <video>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815090/webview-and-html5-video)

Comment: I have been tried above links, they only works when we are using single video tag, but i want to use multiple video tag and play video simultaneously in android 4.2.2

Comment: @Narayansoni I don't see any possible solution here. have you found one?